# Why does skin sometimes suddenly itch when you stretch it?

Tags: physiology, skin

Sometimes, when I bend over, areas of my skin like my back can suddenly itch quite intensely. Sometimes it may be another part of my body and the pattern seems to be a part of the skin organ that is not used to stretching quite that much in that spot, perhaps the skin not being so flexible there.

I realise that temperature, dryness, and a whole lot of other external and internal factors can come into play, but if my scenario is not too broad, and I'm pretty sure it's a universal trait in skin physiology, (and I don't have any skin allergies either), what is the basic science behind this phenomenon of skin stretching when it's not used to it, and you do it very suddenly?

Comment: Do you have stretch marks around the area that itches?

Comment: No the stretching is only minor and the itching momentary (though sharp). The interest is due to the idea that when you stretch the skin, new skin cells are created and it essentially starts expanding if you keep stretching it enough (consistently). So biologically, I wonder what is happening with skin cells when you are doing momentary stretches to skin that isn't already 'expanded' enough for the task, so to speak. I wonder what is happening with the skin cells, because the itch sure is interesting and prominent, biologically. I do think dryness of air/skin is a big factor though, but still.

Comment: you mean relationship between http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21767766 and http://www.humankinetics.com/excerpts/excerpts/anatomy-and-physiology-of-stretching

Comment: I suppose, yes! :) Though not a blanket topical enquiry, more a specific application.